# Training Naive Bayes Classifier on ngrams

Tags: python, ruby, nlp, machine-learning, classification

I've been using the [Ruby Classifier library](http://classifier.rubyforge.org/) to [classify privacy policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709293/interesting-nlp-machine-learning-style-project-analyzing-privacy-policies).  I've come to the conclusion that the simple bag-of-words approach built into this library is not enough.  To increase my classification accuracy, I want to train the classifier on n-grams in addition to individual words.

I was wondering whether there's a library out there for preprocessing documents to get relevant n-grams (and properly deal with punctuation).  One thought was that I could preprocess the documents and feed pseudo-ngrams into the Ruby Classifier like:

> wordone_wordtwo_wordthree

Or maybe there's a better way to be doing this, such as a library that has ngram based Naive Bayes Classification built into it from the getgo.  I'm open to using languages other than Ruby here if they get the job done (Python seems like a good candidate if need be).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're ok with python, I'd say [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/data) would be perfect for you.

For example:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> s = "This is some sample data.  Nltk will use the words in this string to make ngrams.  I hope that this is useful.".split()
>>> model = nltk.NgramModel(2, s)
>>> model._ngrams
set([('to', 'make'), ('sample', 'data.'), ('the', 'words'), ('will', 'use'), ('some', 'sample'), ('', 'This'), ('use', 'the'), ('make', 'ngrams.'), ('ngrams.', 'I'), ('hope', 'that'
), ('is', 'some'), ('is', 'useful.'), ('I', 'hope'), ('this', 'string'), ('Nltk', 'will'), ('words', 'in'), ('this', 'is'), ('data.', 'Nltk'), ('that', 'this'), ('string', 'to'), ('
in', 'this'), ('This', 'is')])
```

You even have a method `nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier`

Comment: NLTK seems amazing in many ways compared to what Ruby has to offer.  Python wins, thank you!

Comment: @babonk my pleasure.  I've found nltk to be a joy to use and incredibly powerful, hope you have fun with it :D

Comment: Hey Nolen, one correction to your example is that you need to `word_tokenize` prior to splitting into ngrams, otherwise it will split on letters :)

Answer (score 3):

```
>> s = "She sells sea shells by the sea shore"
=> "She sells sea shells by the sea shore"
>> s.split(/ /).each_cons(2).to_a.map {|x,y| x + ' ' +  y}
=> ["She sells", "sells sea", "sea shells", "shells by", "by the", "the sea", "sea shore"]
```

Ruby enumerables have a method called enum_cons which will return every of n consecutive items from the enumerable. With that method generating ngrams is a simple one liner.

Comment: Thx. Had to use `each_cons` instead of `enum_cons`.

Comment: Dru: Seems like enum_cons has been deprecated. Replaced it with each_cons in my answer. Thanks!